# Can this summation be simplified?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I got something like

$$
a_{n}
=
{1 \over 4^{n + 1}}\sum_{k = 0}^{\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor}
{n + 1 \choose 2k + 1}\left(-3\right)^{k}
$$

Could this be simplified more?

Comment: Is $k$ the index of summation or the minimum value of the index of summation?

Comment: k is the index of summation, I edited that.

Comment: just for reference, not too sure on how it did it or if it's useful but Mathematica simplified it to: $a_n= \frac{1}{3} 2^{-(n+2)} ( \sqrt{3} \sin(\pi n/3 )+3\cos{(\pi n/3)} )$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from binomial expansion $(1+i\sqrt{3})^{n}$

Notice how the imaginary part rolls out into your sum.